# Selenium Chrome Sendkeys not showing "[" "{"

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

i'm using selenium v3.8.0 and chromedriver 2.35 with c# and when i use this code:

```
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='lst-ib']").SendKeys("[[[]]]");
```

Only writes "]]]" and i don't know why, i think it's a bug. Also happens with "{"

I want an alternative or a solution to write "[" + "any text" and work on anything else without being active onthe chrome webdriver.

Thanks.

GIF https://i.imgur.com/nREQszQ.gif

Comment: Apart from `to write "[" + "any text"` what exactly do you mean by `work on anything else without being active onthe chrome webdriver`

Comment: Like using other software, i want to run webdriber in backgound while i do anything else.

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have? I have Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit) and this https://pastebin.com/H9LCWfxP works for me using Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver v 2.35, Selenium.Support v3.8.0 and Selenium.WebDriver v3.8.0 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: based on the element id, it looks like you're trying to put that into google. I just ran a test and had no issue locating the textbox or sending the keys to it.

Do you think that since you're trying to do other stuff on the computer at the same time maybe you backspaced over those characters or something?

Anyways, use phantomjs instead of chrome driver and you won't have an active window.

Comment: @MattStannett i did wverything u said and still not working, i made a gif so you guys can see more clearly what happens https://i.imgur.com/nREQszQ.gif

Comment: @MiquelTorres try calling the `Clear()` method on the element before `SendKeys()`.

Comment: @MattStannett still not working, what could it be? :(

Comment: @MiquelTorres I have two more suggestions - 1. Try the same code but use FirefoxDriver or InternetExplorerDriver or MicrosoftEdgeDriver instead, if that problem still occurs then go to option 2. Add the English-US locale in the Windows 10 language settings.

Comment: @MiquelTorres if my two suggestions above do not work then you could see if another website eg Bing search has the same issue or if sending through just “[[[“ works correctly. It is a process of elimination to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: @MattStannett i used firefox instead works perfectly but i want to use chrome, but if there's no solution i'll end using firefox hahah, added english language and nothing happens, also tried using the sendkeys in other pages and still doing the same,.

Comment: @MiquelTorres ok so I think the problem is that you're not using the standard US keyboard layout in Windows (which is totally fine - we can use unicode instead). Replace `[` with `\u005B` and `]` with `\u005D`. So that the line of code will look like `driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib")).SendKeys("\u005B\u005B\u005B\u005D\u005D\u005D");`

Comment: @MattStannett still not working, it shows nothing, even if i use english US keyboard

Comment: @MiquelTorres can you zip up your project and upload it somewhere like Dropbox then share the link with me so that I can take a look please.

Comment: @MattStannett Well, i dont know why but today when i ran the program it worked prefectly!!! And it's the same code, hahaha. Also, thank you very much for helping and searching solutions for my ploblem. Thank you Matt.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working in the end.